# Removing Node.Js from Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, node.js, rvm, uninstallation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I completely uninstall Node.js, and reinstall from beginning (Mac OS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x)

I'm trying to remove Node.js from my system so I can reinstall it using the NVM version manager.

I installed Node.js a while ago and according to node `--version`, I'm running `v0.6.8`

I've had a look around but most of the answers i've found are limited to Node being installed via a PKG file and their remedies don't work for me..

Answer (score 57, accepted):

As found by answer [How do I completely uninstall Node.js, and reinstall from beginning (Mac OS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x)

> 1. go to **/usr/local/lib** and delete any **node** and **node_modules**
> 2. go to **/usr/local/include** and delete any **node** and **node_modules** directory
> 3. if you installed with **brew install node**, then run **brew uninstall node** in your terminal
> 4. check your Home directory for any "local" or "lib" or "include" folders, and delete any "node" or "node_modules" from there
> 5. go to **/usr/local/bin** and delete any **node** executable
> 6. go to **/usr/bin and delete** any **node** executable

Comment: You should also remove the man pages. Can't remember which, but type man node after you remove the binaries. You should get a complaint from man.

Comment: You should add to that list:

- /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d
- /usr/local/share/man/man1/node.1

Comment: You should also delete the whole npm stuff.

Comment: I also had to delete /usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp

Comment: Thanks mhkeller, I found that file and deleted it too, but no idea if i needed it. Meh, im reinstalling node via brew anyway, as I had conflicting versions, hence the purge.