# Node won't run, just exits code 0

Tags: node.js

Well some days ago I was tired to always call `sudo` when calling `npm install` and that sort of things so I tried uninstalling node and tried installing via Homebrew, I managed to make a huge disaster but finally it worked. Until now...

When I run `node app.js` or `npm install` it just doesn't do anything.

- I tried deleting the related files like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673327/removing-node-js-from-mountain-lion).
- I tried using [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm).
- Tried the manual install with the .pkg file from the node homepage.
- Tried through homebrew again.

And still no luck; however if the Node app has compilation errors I get the error stack, but when everything is "ok", instead of start listening for incoming connections it just exits with code 0.

Comment: When you just type `node` to use the REPL, does it work?

Comment: Have you tried something simpler, e.g. `console.log('Hello, world!');`? If that works, could you post `app.js`? You might have been using a really old version of Node before, or something.

Comment: @Brad yep that works but no `node app.js` nor `npm install`

Comment: how about `node debug app.js`, does that work?

Comment: Do you by chance have a couple versions of Node.js installed?  `node -v` says what?

Comment: @minitech creating a new project with express works well... still in my project the app.js is untouched since the last day it worked. I even did a git stash to make sure of that

Comment: @OneOfOne I get the following output:

< debugger listening on port 5858
connecting... ok
break in app.js:6
  4  */
  5 
  6 var express = require('express')
  7 ,   http    = require('http')
  8 ,   path    = require('path')
debug>

Comment: After you get to the debug prompt, hit `c`.

Comment: @OneOfOne I get: program terminated

Comment: can you post your app.js? another (painful) thing to try is `node debug app.js` and keep pressing `s` to see where it exits, but that can take a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I feel reaaaaaaaaally stupid after I found the issue, in my postgresql config I had the wrong password for the database and for some reason caused all this mess. Will upvote all of you, will understand if you downvote me for being such a moron.

OneOfOne's `node debug` then keep pressing `s` did the trick for me.

Comment: You can delete your question, if you think it’s not useful — that’ll definitely avoid downvotes. But it’s not that silly :)